# A text file w/ 2 variables seperated by spaces in the same line, has lines with data arranged this way, how to add corresponding data together?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with a distance that accumulates along the lines, adding up, as the first number in each line. Then I have another value seperated by a space from the distance. I want to create a program that adds the distances together and the other values together. 
So far I have only this, that reads the data from the text file:

```
filename = "datacarlog.txt"
infile = open(filename, "r")
distance = 0
fuel = 0
lines = infile.readlines()
for line in lines:
    data = line.strip().split(" ")
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to add the values in the list you have created: `data`. You can do this by using the indexes of this list by adding this to the end of the for loop:

```
distance += int(data[0])
fuel += int(data[1])
```

This will add the first value in the list `data` with `data[0]` and second value with `data[1]` to the corresponding variables. The `+=` is just a short hand way of writing `distance = distance + data[x]`. This will repeat for every line in your file.